# convert existing local datetime entries to UTC

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bunch of datetime entries in my database that now has to be migrated to UTC.

I've tried something like this to verify the time-difference:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,GetUTCDate()),'+02:00')) Time_In_Sweden
```

Local (+2h) to UTC (+0) => i.e. **I have to remove 2h.**

But i'm not sure how i would go about when executing this query. Is there better ways of doing this?

The datetime column is of type `datetime2(7)` and called `DateCreated`

I've tried this, but doesn't work and i'm not sure how to do it.

```
DECLARE @Time_In_Sweden datetime2, @UTCTimeNow datetime2
SET @Time_In_Sweden = DateCreated   -- ????????
SET @UTCTimeNow = GETUTCDATE()

UPDATE MachineStops SET DateCreated = CONVERT(DATEDIFF(d,DateCreated,@UTCTimeNow)
```

*MachineStops is the table*

Thanks.

Comment: Are you taking into account daylight savings time in Sweden? https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/sweden/stockholm

Comment: @dfundako yes (unfortunately)

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you know that time difference is 2 hours, easiest way is to just take those 2 hours off:

```
Update MachineStops SET DateCreated = DateADD(hour, -2, DateCreated )
```

Comment: Yes of course... been converting between different locales in TS... I thought it would be more complicated in sql lol. Thanks